# JSON with AngularJS: parent in nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

according to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839743/angularjs-nested-ng-repeat) i built my AngularJS app. Now i want to access a parent's value **within** a nested structure.

I tried this, but it does not work: http://jsfiddle.net/BwDAP/

```
<body  ng-app="WeeklyApp" ng-controller="WeeklyController" >
    <div ng-repeat="week in myData">
       <div ng-repeat="day in week.days">
          {{day.dow}} - {{day.templateDay}}
          <b>Jobs:</b><br/> 
           <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="job in day.jobs"> 
               {{job.name}} 
                 <br />
               <!-- PARENT -->
               parent: {{job.parent.dow}} 
             </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Any solutions?
thx

Answer (score 0):

A haha, too easy ;-) 
Here is the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Lm6KZ/

```
<body  ng-app="WeeklyApp" ng-controller="WeeklyController" >
    <div ng-repeat="week in myData">
       <div ng-repeat="day in week.days">
          {{day.dow}} - {{day.templateDay}}
          <b>Jobs:</b><br/> 
           <ul>
             <li ng-repeat="job in day.jobs"> 
               {{job.name}} 
                 <br />
               <!-- PARENT -->
               parent: {{day.dow}} 
             </li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</body>
```