# Fetch multi level(nested) JSON data and show data in Ionic App

Tags: json, cordova, ionic-framework

**Hi friends**

I need to show some social icon in ionic app based on JSON data, but the problem I am not able to fetch multi level JSON data not able to show on screen.

**Need to look like:**

[image]

**JSON data**

```
{
"candidates": [
    {
        "id": "0",
        "socialmedia": [
            {
                "network": "linkend",
                "url": "https://www.linkend.com",
                "icon": "https://www.example.com/images/linkend.png"
            },{
                "network": "skype",
                "url": "https://www.skype.com",
                "icon": "https://www.example.com/images/skype.png"
            },{
                "network": "google",
                "url": "https://www.google.com",
                "icon": "https://www.example.com/images/google.png"
            },{
                "network": "yahoo",
                "url": "https://www.yahoo.com",
                "icon": "https://www.example.com/images/yahoo.png"
            }
        ],
    },{
        "id": "1",
        "socialmedia": [
            {
                "network": "facebook",
                "url": "https://www.facebook.com",
                "icon": "https://www.example.com/images/facebook.png"
            },{
                "network": "linkend",
                "url": "https://www.linkend.com",
                "icon": "https://www.example.com/images/linkend.png"
            },{
                "network": "google",
                "url": "https://www.google.com",
                "icon": "https://www.example.com/images/google.png"
            },{
                "network": "yahoo",
                "url": "https://www.yahoo.com",
                "icon": "https://www.example.com/images/yahoo.png"
            }
        ],
    },{
        "id": "2",
        "socialmedia": [
            {
                "network": "facebook",
                "url": "https://www.facebook.com",
                "icon": "https://www.example.com/images/facebook.png"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

Please Help Me, Thanks in Advance

Comment: i cannot understand your question. You want to fetch the icon from those social?

Comment: @gianlucatursi Thanks for your reply. No, I want only to show that json data to my app look like in above pic. The problem that I am not able to fetch "socialmedia" data and not able to bind in app page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show social icons for each candidate, you can have nested ng-repeat as shown something like below:

```
<div ng-repeat="candidate in candidates">
    <div ng-repeat="socialLink in candidate.socialmedia">
       <a href="{{socialLink.url}}"><div class="{{socialLink.network}}></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can define some css classes based on the socialmedia networks and use those class names in your html to display the images (check the below css for your reference. This is just an example for your understanding and not the exact css definitions you will use)

```
.facebook {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("facebook-icon.png");
}
.linkedin {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("linkedin-icon.png");
}
.another-network {
  display: inline-block;
  background-image: url("another-network-icon.png");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Prasad, You save my day!!.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
    var test={
"candidates": [
    {
        "id": "0",
        "socialmedia": [
            {
                "network": "facebook",
                "url": "https://www.facebook.com"
            },{
                "network": "linkend",
                "url": "https://www.linkend.com"
            },{
                "network": "skype",
                "url": "https://www.skype.com"
            },{
                "network": "google",
                "url": "https://www.google.com"
            },{
                "network": "yahoo",
                "url": "https://www.google.com"
            }
        ]
    }
]
}; 
var socialmedia=test.candidates[0].socialmedia;
for(var i in socialmedia){
alert(socialmedia[i].url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to store the response in $scope variable like this

```
$scope.socialmedia=response.candidates[0].socialmedia;
```

In Your View

```
 <div ng-repeat="img in socialmedia">
    <img ng-src="img/{{img.network}}.jpeg" >
    </div>
```

**Note**  the images should be stored in your www folder,  based on the name it will display or else you can directly call it from server

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i try your code I face problem that json data is for different different **ID** and I need to show social network images based on there ID page