# AngularJS iterating through a multi-layered array with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I have an issue with the ng-repeat directive when it comes to iterating through an array with multiple layers. Much like a Json object but not quite.

To build the array I use code akin to this:

```
$scope.dailyData = []
$scope.dailyData[0] = []
$scope.dailyData[0].push([{"today":null,"day2":1,"day3":null,"day4":null,"day5":null,"day6":null,"day7":null,"title":"Queries Built","id":null}])
```

This is just a sample of what the program actually does, and I do it this way for a specific reason that may or may not be relevant to the question.

This outputs to an array that looks like this.

```
[[[{"title":"Queries Built","today":null,"day2":1,"day3":null,"day4":null,"id":null}]]]
```

There are three arrays and an object in the middle. The problem is I can't seem to get the ng-repeat to pull the data from the object.

I want it to output like this:

```
|     Title     | Today | Yesterday |
| Queries Built |  null |     1     |
```

But everything I've tried on ng-repeat doesn't seem to work. One such example:

```
<div ng-repeat="row in dailyData[0]">
    <tr>
        <td>{{row[0]["title"]}}</td>
        <td>{{row["today"]}}</td>
        <td>{{row["day2"]}}</td>
        <td>{{row["day3"]}}</td>
        <td>{{row["day4"]}}</td>
    </tr>
</div>
```

The first row in here is a different method from the others, neither of them works.

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rms9dv8j/2/

Comment: You need another array reference, like this "row in dailyData[0][0]" I won't ask why you have 3 nested arrays, presumably you have good reason for that :)

Comment: When I do row in dailyData[0][0] then later try row["title"] nothing shows up. I'm currently trying to get a fiddle running to share

Comment: Added the fiddle to the OP.

Comment: you should be able to reference your nested data by giving it a name. For example, dailyData.array[0].array2[0]

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you meant when you left the answer below, I'll try that out and let you know how it goes. I was reluctant because I'm working around an already created system.

Comment: I edited the plunker in my answer below. It references by indexes too now. Let me know if I can help any other way.

Comment: Actually, would that be able to be used dynamically? I have it the way it is now because, in conjunction with rails, I am able to change the dailyData[0] with dailyData[<%= index %>]. I could probably explain the entire process as well if need be.

Comment: I don't think Angular will be able to handle that. You may have to try some other trick or way around that. I found this article that might be helpful to you: https://spin.atomicobject.com/2013/11/22/pass-rails-data-angularjs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that you used a `<DIV>` tag in the middle of the table, which is probably why the browser didn't render anything.

In this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5ox7Ledw/

```
<div ng-repeat="row in dailyData[0][0]">
    <tr>
        <td>{{row[0]["title"]}}</td>
```

I simplified the data and moved the ng-repeat into the TR element, while also deleting the erroneous DIV

```
<tr ng-repeat="row in dailyData">
    <td>{{row.title}}</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to restructure your data so that it is in a better format.

You will need to do a nested loop similar to what I've done in this plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/CqUHwj?p=info

```
<div ng-app="module" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="row in array">
     {{row.name}}
     <div ng-repeat="row2 in row.array2">
       {{row2.name}}
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

More helpful information can be found in this post:

[Nested ng-repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839743/nested-ng-repeat)