# How to dynamically load the nested array attributes in html table using angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, dynamic-tables

This is the code that I tried but only values of cardno and cardtype why am I not able to access the rest of them? Any suggestions?

```
<tr ng-repeat="data in myData17.layouts">
  <td ng-show="$index==1">{{data.name}}</td>
  <td ng-show="$index==1">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="card in data.cards">
        <td>{{card.cardNo}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td ng-show="$index==1">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="card in data.cards">
        <td>{{card.cardType}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td ng-show="$index==1">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="card in data.cards.ports">
        <td>{{card.portNo}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td ng-show="$index==1">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="card in data.cards.ports">
        <td>{{card.portName}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td ng-show="$index==1">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="card in data.cards.ports">
        <td>{{card.portType}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td ng-show="$index==1">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="card in data.cards.ports">
        <td>{{card.portspeed}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
  <td ng-show="$index==1">
    <table>
      <tr ng-repeat="card in data.cards.ports">
        <td>{{card["ds-scheduler-node-profile"]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

This is the my data.

```
      {
  "name": "twoCardOneEthportAndOne10G",
  "cards": [{
    "cardNo": "1",
    "cardType": "Ethernet",
    "ports": [{
      "portNo": "1",
      "portName": "LAN1",
      "portType": "ethernetCsmacd",
      "portspeed": "eth-if-speed-1gb",
      "ds-scheduler-node-profile": "default"
    }]
  },
    {
      "cardNo": "10",
      "cardType": "Ethernet",
      "ports": [{
        "portNo": "1",
        "portName": "10GE",
        "portType": "ethernetCsmacd",
        "portspeed": "eth-if-speed-10gb",
        "ds-scheduler-node-profile": "default"
      }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: Please check this for solution [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839743/nested-ng-repeat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**data.cards.ports** isn’t a thing.

The **ports** property is of a singular **card** and **cards** is an array.

It would have to be accessed like so:

```
data.cards[0].ports
```

So, how would this be structured in your code? You would need something like this (this isn’t a solution to your exact implementation just a visual guide to help you access your data in the way you require)

```
<div ng-repeat=“data in myData17.layouts”>
    {{ data.name }}
    <div ng-repeat=“card in data.cards”>
        {{ card.cardNo }}
        <div ng-repeat=“port in card.ports”>
            {{ port.portNo }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope that this gives you a better understanding and good luck